# Null Pointer Exception: Android

Tags: android

I am currently encountering a `NullPointerException`. I have used log statements to realize that it it shuts down when one specific line of code is read.

I have read lots about this type of exception, however I don't understand what is wrong with this specific statement.

```
try {

    Log.i(TAG, "1"); // Breaks here
    mDiaryId = ContentUris.parseId(launchingIntent.getData());
    Log.i(TAG, "2");

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "3");
    mDiaryId = -1;
}
```

Comment: Have you debug it yet? Probably it has something to do with launchingIntent being null

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for `null` after calling `launchingIntent.getData()`. Like this.

```
try {

    Log.i(TAG, "1");
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    if (data != null) { // <-- check data for null
        mDiaryId = ContentUris.parseId(data);
    } else {
        mDiaryId = -1;
        Log.i(TAG, "Data is null");
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "2");

} catch (NumberFormatException e){
    Log.i(TAG, "3");
    mDiaryId = -1;
}
```

Comment: I feel the launchingIntent itself is null and hence trying to do launchingIntent.getData() is throwing a NPE.

Comment: If your launching intent is taken from getIntent(), then it's never null.

Comment: Ohh you modified.Didnt see that. :) I was trying pointing out use of launchingIntent directly to barry.

Comment: Yeah that's worked, however I now have the same error further down. I will get my head around it one day. Thank you

Comment: Just remember, that getData() returns null, if your activity gets called by an intent without data assigned.